# Ghostscript adding a on one page, avoid processing all pages (for speed reasons)?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

We try to add a small link to a large PDF 50 pages and more. The command

```
gs \
 -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE \
 -o output.pdf \
 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
 -c "[ /Rect [1 1 15 15]" \
 -c "  /Color [1 1 1]" \
 -c "  /Page 1" \
 -c "  /Action <</Subtype /URI" \
 -c "  /URI (http://www.google.de/searchxy)>>" \
 -c "  /Subtype /Link" \
 -c "  /ANN pdfmark" \
 -f input.pdf
```

works great! The link is added on the selected page.

**Problem**: Ghostscript parses all pages of the document - even it does no changes. This causes huge time lost.

**Question**: how can we tell Ghostscript to work just on page 1 and leave all other pages as they are to be much faster in processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The way Ghostscript and the pdfwrite device work is described in ghostpdl/doc/VectorDevices.htm or [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.25/VectorDevices.htm#Overview).

I'd suggest you read that to see why this isn't possible, and also to gain some understanding of what's actually going on. You are not simply 'adding a link' you are creating a completely new PDF file, whose contents (at the file level) may bear no relation to the original PDF file's contents.

Ghostscript + pdfwrite is not a 'PDF editor'/